# PHP5.6 are arrays allowed in CLASS constants

Tags: php, arrays, class, constants, php-5.6

So we can define array constants in PHP5.6. However, I got the following error when defining an array constant inside a class

```
Arrays are not allowed in class constants
```

So is it true that array constants are allowed but not inside classes?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As of PHP 5.6 arrays are allowed in class constants.

See the [link](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d50f416563c2b5cfa163f2f242f520ab54762a46) for a working php code.

```
<?php

class Foo 
{
    const BAR = [1,2,3];
}

print_r(Foo::BAR);
```

Comment: https://3v4l.org/T44gG - 3v4l link showing version compatibility. Worth noting that they aren't supported at all in HHVM.